# Read in Username and Password from File previously created Java

Tags: java

I writing Username + "" + Password out to a file. However Im not sure how to read in the file and then check if User or password is correct in any of the added usernames and passwords, thus letting a user into my program. not allowed to use a database for this project.

```
 public void writeToFile(String Username, String Password) throws IOException{
       BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/josephdawson/Desktop/LoginInfo.txt", true));
       out.write(Username + " " + Password);
       out.newLine();
       out.close();
   }
   public void readFromFile() throws IOException{
    String filePath = "/Users/josephdawson/Desktop/LoginInfo.txt";
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    try{
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/josephdawson/Desktop/LoginInfo.txt"));
        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
           if(line.equals(nUsername) && line.equals(nPassword)){
        
           }
       }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
   }
```

Here is the Action Method that calls write to file

```
            String NewUsername = nUsername.getText();
            String NewPassword = nPassword.getText();
           try {
               writeToFile(NewUsername,NewPassword);
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(ProjectGame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
            newLoginWin.setVisible(false);
            genderGui.setVisible(true);
       }
```

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question. Please [edit] the post and add a specific question.

Comment: `catch(FileNotFoundException e){` - never silently ignore exceptions

Answer (score 1):

How can the line equal both?

```
if(line.equals(nUsername) && line.equals(nPassword)){
```

You wrote it to the file as

```
out.write(Username + " " + Password);
```

so it needs to be in this format when you read it.

```
if(line.equals(nUsername + " " + nPassword)){
```